Unable to update from macOS Sequoia Public Beta 8 to RC
I've been trying to update from Public Beta 8 to RC for the last couple of days, and it always fails with one of the following errors:


Some days it shows the first error, some days the second one.
Upon inspecting the system logs, I found that every time I try to update it, a file /System/Volumes/Update/restore.log is created, and that file contains the following error:
16dcf7000 : Failed to create paired recoveryOS local boot policy: image4 (6) (6)
16dcf7000 : MobileSoftwareUpdateErrorDomain error 43 - Failed to create paired recoveryOS local boot policy: image4 (6) (6)
16dcf7000 : leaving create_local_bootpolicy_with_options_for_volume_uuid
16dcf7000 : MobileSoftwareUpdateErrorDomain error 43 - Failed to create local BootPolicy for SFR
16dcf7000 : End preflight personalizing SFR.
16dcf7000 : target controller popped: (
)
16dcf7000 : error Error Domain=MobileSoftwareUpdateErrorDomain Code=43 "Failed to create local BootPolicy for SFR" UserInfo={target_update=24A335, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create local BootPolicy for SFR, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000023868b0 {Error Domain=MobileSoftwareUpdateErrorDomain Code=43 "Failed to create paired recoveryOS local boot policy: image4 (6) (6)" UserInfo={target_update=24A335, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create paired recoveryOS local boot policy: image4 (6) (6), NSUnderlyingError=0x600002386790 {Error Domain=com.apple.bootpolicy Code=6 "(null)"}}}} preflight personalizing SFR.


It is a beta so assume it will fail and restore from your backup and a release version of OS. Also report this issue to Apple.

As I was not able to update my Sequoia Beta 8 even to the final/public release, I went through the "DFU Revive" process (described here: https://support.apple.com/en-ie/108900#help). The whole process took a little bit more than an hour (you need a secondary MacBook with Sequoia), and after completing it, I was finally able to update my MacBook without any issues. From my understanding, my recoveryOS volume was somehow damaged, which prevented the update, and the DFU Revive process fixed that volume.

Excellent, glad you didn’t need to restore or erase!

The easy path is backup with Time Machine and then attempt erase all content and settings, run the update, next do an erase install.
It’s not entirely clear what you want to accomplish since your question is mostly a statement and not a clear goal you have stated publicly to reach.
Perhaps it’s make a USB bootable installer? Perhaps it’s how to reverse engineer the failed process?

If you just want to be on the official release then you should wait. Turn off beta releases and wait for another update and try again.
If you have a reason to be more urgent, or need the installer for another partition then you may be able to download the installer using Terminal:
sudo software update --download-full-installer --full-installer-version 15.0

